# Oracle select - multiple parameters one column

Tags: sql, oracle, select, stored-procedures

I have a table with columns like this:

```
ID number
Adress varchar2
Message varchar2
```

Address can have email or phone

And I have a stored procedure like this:

```
PROCEDURE get_messages (
  i_email                   IN     varchar2,
  i_phone                   IN     varchar2
  o_messages    OUT     messages)
BEGIN
```

Which gets email, phone or both.

And in this procedure I want to select messages like this:

- If i_email and i_phone both are `nulls` I want to select all messages
- If i_email is not `null` and i_phone is `null` I want to select all
  messages sent to that email
- If i_phone is not `null` and i_email is `null` I want to select all
  messages sent to that phone

  - If i_email and i_phone both are not `nulls` I want to select all messages sent to i_email and i_phone

I have a difficult time to write select like like this.

```
  SELECT * FROM MESSAGES
  WHERE (Address = i_email OR i_email IS NULL)
         OR
        (Address = i_phone OR i_phone IS NULL)
```

But it works only if both values are not `nulls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM   MESSAGES
WHERE  ( i_email IS NULL
         AND i_phone IS NULL )
        OR ( i_email IS NOT NULL
             AND i_phone IS NULL
             AND Address = i_email )
        OR ( i_phone IS NOT NULL
             AND i_email IS NULL
             AND Address = i_phone )
        OR ( Address = i_email
             OR i_phone = Address )
```

Comment: Thank you it works but why did you added 1=1, I removed it and it seems that it works anyway

Comment: @user2412672 pass both values as `NULL` then it won't work without 1=1

Comment: Not sure you need either of the 'IS NOT NULL' clauses; and the last `OR` clause can't ever be matches, as Address can't have two values simultaneously?

Comment: I needed to rewrite last OR to this OR ( Address = i_email
             OR i_phone = Address )